# autossh pid is not equal to the one in pidfile when using start-stop-daemon

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, autossh

I am trying to create a service on my Debian Wheezy system.

When trying to use start-stop-daemon to run autossh, the pid contained into the pidfile does not match with the autossh process.

```
$ AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/var/run/padstunnel.pid
$ sudo start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --background --name mytunnel --start --pidfile /var/run/mytunnel.pid --exec /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -- -M 0 -p 22 user@server -f -T -N -R 31022:localhost:31222
$ ps -elf |grep autossh
1 S root       447     1  0  80   0 -   329 pause  19:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 0 -p 22 ...
$ cat /var/run/mytunnel.pid
446
```

This behaviour prevents from stopping `autossh` using start-stop-daemon or kill it using the pid from the pidfile.

Is there any reason to this behaviour ?

How to workaround it and make autossh's pid matches the pidfile ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `AUTOSSH_PIDFILE` variable and having `autossh` write the pid file itself?

Comment: Yes, with the same result

Comment: That's because `-f` tells autossh to drop into the background. (i.e. fork). Try removing it.

Comment: removing `-f`` option does not work well neither: two processes are then created by autossh, and pidfile's pid does not match the root process. See more info in the answer I found.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found is inspired by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/285739/139286).

Actually, the `AUTOSSH_PIDFILE` variable could not be used by `autossh` (because start-stop-daemon runs in a different environment).

So the workaround is to use :

```
$ sudo start-stop-daemon --background --name mytunnel --start --exec /usr/bin/env AUTOSSH_PIDFILE="/var/run/mytunnel.pid" /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -- -M 0 -p 22 user@server -f -T -N -R 31022:localhost:31222
```

- `/usr/bin/env AUTOSSH_PIDFILE="/var/run/mytunnel.pid"` correctly defines the necessary environment variable
- `--make-pidfile` and `--pidfile` are no longer required by `start-stop-daemon`
- `sudo start-stop-daemon --pidfile /var/run/mytunnel.pid  --stop` now works to kill `autossh`
- `--background` option makes the `ssh`'s `-f` optional (using `-f` or not does not change anything if `--background` is used)

The reason for the behaviour is not completely clear to me. However, it seems that `autossh` automatically creates several processes to handle correctly `ssh` instances when it does not see `AUTOSSH_PIDFILE` variable.

**Edit:**

When using it from a service init script (in /etc/init.d/servicename), the syntax has to be modified:

```
sudo start-stop-daemon --background --name mytunnel --start --exec /usr/bin/env -- AUTOSSH_PIDFILE="/var/run/mytunnel.pid" /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 0 -p 22 user@server -f -T -N -R 31022:localhost:31222
```

Notice the `--` that must come just after the /usr/bin/env command (it was after the /usr/lib/autossh/autossh from command line).

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for a working solution from 7 years into the future as I recently came across this exact same issue.

The `AUTOSSH_PIDFILE` variable for some reason will make the program fail without any output, including when using `-v`. What I found would work is simply foregoing `-f` on autossh and using `--background` on the start-stop-daemon. Apparently this also necessitates the `-N` flag on autossh, which is as best I can tell undocumented.

Could be a new development or upstream issues, but in any case the answer by OP did not work for me, but this did:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background --user myuser --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile "/var/run/myhost_autossh.pid" --exec autossh -- -M 0 -N myhost
```